# Powershell Multiple TextBox into one line?

Tags: powershell-ise

This does give the output from the first and second textbox, but I want it to look like this:

**ABC:DEF**

But this script gives me:

**ABC : DEF**

I do not want that space. The script:

```
    $text = $firstTextBox.Text,':',$secondTextBox.Text
    ...
    Add-Content $ScriptDir\test.txt "$text"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this: `$text = $firstTextBox.Text + ':' + $secondTextBox.Text`